# How to repeat a step in a loop if an action fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

In the case I am looping into a list, where for value `msg_list = 0` it will execute `action(0), usr)`. This action can fail for a determined user, I should choose aother user if it happens, perform all the actions related to the user

How can I do to repeat action[0] if it fails?

```
for msg in range(len(msg_list)):
  # in this case msg = 0
  usr = select_random_user()
  multiple_actions_for(usr)       # This are lots of code lines I don't want to repeat!!
  try:
    action(msg, usr)
    more_actions(usr.related_stuff)
  except Exception as e:
    go_back_to(msg =0 instead of looping into msg=1) # this is what I want to do
```

How can I do to get that? Repeat the loop for `msg = i` instead of passing to `msg = i + 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Put your code into the endless `while`-loop with exiting from it if `try` was successful:

```
for msg in range(len(msg_list)):
    while True:
        usr = select_random_user()
        multiple_actions_for(usr)
        try:
            action(msg, usr)
            more_actions(usr.related_stuff)
        except Exception as e:
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. Is it okay to go back to the beginning of the loop? If so, you can call "continue", which stops the current iteration, and restarts the loop. Otherwise, I don't think there's something similar to a goto in Python, no. It's a very structured language.

Answer (score 0):

Try using while loop instead of for loop. The idea is as shown bellow:

```
bool still_looping = True
msg = 0

while still_looping:
    usr = select_random_user()
    multiple_actions_for(usr)
    try:
        action(msg, usr)
        more_actions(usr.related_stuff)
        if (msg < len (msg_list)):
            msg += 1
    except Exception as e:
        # Do whatever you want here. msg was not incremented
    if (msg == len(msg_list))
        still_looping = False #verify if this was the last execution
```